# Why isn't the JTable resizing properly?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, window-resize, autoresize

## Why isn't the JTable resizing properly?

Hello and thanks for taking the time to deal with my problem. First let me introduce you to my dummy-/training-project. The classes listed below should represent a programm after the MVC-model (Model, View, Controller). When running the main class a FileChooser opens up, from which you're able to select a .csv-File that contains information that is saved as a String[][]. This String[][] is then visualized in the view-class as a JTable. This JTable is part of a JPanel inside a JFrame with the BorderLayout.CENTER. Now to the question, why wont my JTable resize properly if i am rezising the JFrame? I searched on the internet and even `this.table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);` will not effect the resizing at all. I hope you can help me somehow. Thanks!

## The MVC-classes + testclass

### Model

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class is responsible for the actual data being "processed".
 * It saves the Strings out of a File into a String[][] and further more updates its content,
 * if changed by the View-Class.
 * 
 * @author CodeScrub
 * @version 2022-01-13
 */

public class Model {

    private File selectedFile;
    
    private String[][] dataSetTotal;
    private ArrayList<String> dataSetList;
    
    private ArrayList<String> tableDatasetList;
    
    public Model() {
        dataSetList = new ArrayList<String>();
        tableDatasetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    
    public void evaluateData() {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.selectedFile);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = scanner.nextLine();
                dataSetList.add(data);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        this.dataSetTotal = new String[dataSetList.size()][3];
        
        for(String info : dataSetList) {
            String[] dataSetSeperate = info.split(";");
            for(int i = 0; i < dataSetSeperate.length; i++) {
                dataSetTotal[dataSetList.indexOf(info)][i] = dataSetSeperate[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void setSelectedFile(File selectedFile) {
        this.selectedFile = selectedFile;
    }
    
    public File getSelectedFile() {
        return this.selectedFile;
    }
    
    public String[][] getDataSetTotal(){
        return this.dataSetTotal;
    }
    
    public void updateData(String[][] tableContent) {
        for(int i = 0; i < tableContent.length; i++) {
            String dataSetSeperate = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < tableContent[i].length; j++) {
                if(j < 2) {
                    dataSetSeperate = dataSetSeperate + tableContent[i][j] + ";";
                }else {
                    dataSetSeperate = dataSetSeperate + tableContent[i][j];
                }
            }
            this.tableDatasetList.add(dataSetSeperate);
        }
        
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.selectedFile));
            for(String info : this.tableDatasetList){
                writer.write(info + "\n");
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.tableDatasetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

### View

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

/**
 * This class visualizes the processed data inside a JFrame.
 * The data sets are visualized as a JTable.
 * 
 * @author CodeScrub
 * @version 2022-01-13
 */

public class View extends JFrame{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private JFileChooser chooser;
    private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;
    
    private JLabel firstName;
    private JLabel lastName;
    private JLabel socialSecurityNumber;
    
    private JButton buttonSafeChanges;
    
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    
    private JTable table;
    
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    
    private Controller controller;
    
    public View(Controller controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
        init();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        this.chooser = new JFileChooser();
        this.filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "CSV Files", "csv");
        this.chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        this.chooser.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            this.controller.updateData(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            this.controller.evaluateData();
            
            this.firstName = new JLabel("First Name");
            this.lastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
            this.socialSecurityNumber = new JLabel("Social Security Number");
            
            this.centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            
            String[] title = {firstName.getText() , lastName.getText() , socialSecurityNumber.getText()}; 
            this.table = new JTable(this.controller.getDataSetTotal(), title);
            this.table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
            this.centerPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
            this.centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
            
            this.buttonSafeChanges = new JButton("Safe Changes");
            this.buttonSafeChanges.addActionListener(controller);
            
            this.centerPanel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.add(buttonSafeChanges, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.setTitle("MVC");
            this.setSize(475,350);
            this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(475,350));
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setVisible(true);
            getTableContent();
        }else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    public JButton getButtonSafeChanges() {
        return this.buttonSafeChanges;
    }
    
    public String[][] getTableContent() {
        String[][] tableContent;
        tableContent = new String[this.table.getRowCount()][this.table.getColumnCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                tableContent[i][j] = table.getValueAt(i,j).toString();
            }
        }
        return tableContent;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
import java.io.File;

/**
 * This class works as an interface between the view- and model-class 
 * and also handles the action performed after the button press "Safe Changes".
 * 
 * @author CodeScrub
 * @version 2022-01-13
 */

public class Controller implements ActionListener{

    private View view;
    private Model model;
    
    public Controller() {
        this.model = new Model();
        this.view = new View(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == this.view.getButtonSafeChanges()) {
            this.model.updateData(this.view.getTableContent());
        }
    }
    
    public void updateData(File selectedFile) {
        this.model.setSelectedFile(selectedFile);
    }
    
    public File getSelectedFile() {
        return this.model.getSelectedFile();
    }
    
    public void evaluateData() {
        this.model.evaluateData();
    }
    
    public String[][] getDataSetTotal(){
        return this.model.getDataSetTotal();
    }
}
```

### Test-class:

```
public class MVC_Testclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add the JTable multiple times to the GUI? You're placing it into a JScrollPane, which is good, but then trying to add both the naked JTable and the JScrollPane to the GUI (and even the JTable's header), which is not good. Add the JScrollPane to the GUI and do not try to add the JTable again, and same for the table's header.

Comment: Wow such an easy fix, thank you. It is the first time I am working with the JScrollPane, so I didnt realize that it's behaviour is similar to an JPanel. I didn't think that ```this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);``` would actually visually add it to the Frame.

Comment: No, that line does not add the scroll pane to the JFrame. It is where you call .add(scrollPane) that it gets added.  Rather the line that you show above places the JTable into the JScrollPane's viewport. Then you add the JScrollPane into the GUI into a JPanel's BorderLayout.CENTER position, which is good, but you can add a component only *once* to a GUI, and if you re-add any components then you remove it from where it was previously added.

Comment: I should rephrase that. I thought ```this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);``` actually adds the "scrollbar" to the table. I didn't know JScrollPane's behaviour was like a JPanel or JFrame where you can add something like a JTable.

Comment: Check the Oracle JScrollPane tutorial as it is an interesting compound component, one that has a lot of uses, even sometimes without the scrollbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, as you are using JScrollPane container for your JTable, you only need to add the `scrollPane` in your `centerPanel`, and make sure to add it in the `CENTER`. The below resolves the issue in your code.

```
this.table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
//this.centerPanel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);

this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.table);
this.centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```